# Make CloudSolrServer to run dataimports only on a leader

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, solrcloud

I set up a two servers Solr cluster with SolrCloud. Currently I have Master and Replica.

I want to dataimports go to the leader since it doesn't make any sense to make delta-imports on slave (updates wouldn't be distributed to the leader).

From the documentation I get that CloudSolrServer knows cluster state (obtained from Zookeeper) and by default sends all updates only to the leader.

What I want is to make CloudSolrServer to send all dataimport commands to the master. I have the following code:

```
        SolrServer solrServer = new CloudSolrServer("localhost:2181");
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set("qt", "/dataimport");
        params.set("command", "delta-import");
        QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(params);
```

But I see that the requests still goes to both my servers 
localhost:8080 and localhost:8983. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your solr server initialization to below

```
SolrServer solrServer = new CloudSolrServer("zkHost1:port,zkHost2:port");
```

THis will cause the solr server client to consult zookeeper for solrcloud state.
For more details read CloudSolrServer documentation to init from zookeeper ensemble.

Answer (score -2):

```html
try { CloudSolrServer css = new CloudSolrServer("host1:2181,host2:2181"); css.connect(); ZkStateReader zkSR2 = css.getZkStateReader(); String leader = zkSR2.getLeaderUrl("collection_name", "shard1", 10); } catch (KeeperException e) { } catch (IOException
e) { } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```